# Using JQuery to generate HTML, then .html() to alter it. OK in FF but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am utilising the JQuery cycle plugin.

The plugin genereates an image slider with numbered links to swap between images. I want to change the numbered links to some HTML of my own (eg: change '1' to 'My string'), so I created:

```
$('#nav a').html(function(i, html) {
    return $.trim(html) == '1' ? '<h2>Lorem</h2>' : html;
    return $.trim(html) == '2' ? '<h2>Dolar Sit</h2>' : html;
    return $.trim(html) == '3' ? '<h2>Amet</h2>' : html;
    return $.trim(html) == '4' ? '<h2>Ipsum</h2>' : html;

});
```

This works fine in Fire Fox, but not Chrome. I believe this is because the numbered links were not part of the original DOM, and so Chrome has difficulty going back to find and alter it.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

EDIT:

What I see in chrome is:

> 1 2 3 4 5

What I see in Fire Fox (and what I want to achieve) is:

> Lorem Dolar Sit Amet Ipsum

Comment: What are the contents of `#nav`? Are there multiple `a` inside? Are you trying to replace the contents? What does FireFox output that Chrome isn't?

Comment: Your code will always execute the first return statement. Did you check your logic?

Comment: This is not related to your issue, but your function will never reach the 2nd, 3rd or 4th row

Comment: @ShankarSangoli yes - the plugin is situated prior to the above code

Comment: Can you fiddle it and provide a link which has this issue?

Comment: @couzzi yes there are multiple a tags. FF outputs the changes in the HTML, Chrome does not

Comment: Can you post Firefox's output so we can know what we're working towards?

Answer (score 0):

Your multiple `returns` are unreachable after the first `return`. That's causing JS errors.

A handy way to achieve the desired could be:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/amicuf/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){ // DOM READY

    var definedText = {
        1 : "<h2>Lorem</h2>",
        2 : "<h2>Dolar Sit</h2>",
        3 : "<h2>Amet</h2>",
        4 : "<h2>Ipsum</h2>"
    };

    $('#nav a').html(function(i, html) {

      var trHTML = $.trim(html);
      return definedText[trHTML] || html;

    });

});
```

definedText is just an object that will compare for the trimmed HTML.
if no match found will simply return the already existent HTML.